# Applying CLT to DCT transform

Tags: central-limit-theorem

$ x_n $ is a discrete uniform variable on [-128, 127]. I use this function to derive DCT coefficients of $x_n$:
$$ X_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \cos[\frac{\pi}N (n+\frac{1}2) k] \qquad k=0,...,N-1 $$
The histogram of coefficients ($X_k$) shows a Gaussian distribution. Could anyone please bring a theoretical justification for it? I couldn't apply Central Limit Theorem (and even Lyapunov and Lindeberg CLT) to it.

Thanks in advance.

**Added information:**
This simple Matlab code represents my experiment:

```
signal_length = 8192;
data = randi([-128, 127], 1, signal_length);
fdata = dct(data);

subplot(211);
hist(data,signal_length);
title('Histogram of data');
subplot(212);
hist(fdata,signal_length);
title('Histogram of DCT coefficients');
```

[image]

I couldn't add the image of the code output to this post!

Comment: Really $X_k$ depends on $N$ and should be written $X_{k,N}$.  Shall we presume you want to demonstrate that for any *fixed* $k$, the limiting distribution of the standardized version of $X_{k,N}$ is standard Normal as $N\to\infty$?  (None of the $X_{k,N}$ is truly Normal.)  Alternatively, if you don't want to fix $k$, do you want to fix $k/N$? What are you actually trying to justify?  (Of course we're assuming the $x_n$ are independent.)

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I try to explain it in a simpler way. Please make any assumptions needed to resolve the problem. $N$ is equal to 8192 in my experiments. So, I calculate 8192 values for $X_k$. When I plot the histogram of the resulted values for $X_k$, a Gaussian distribution is seen. I want to theoretically discuss the reason of appearing a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: What data do you use to compute these $X_k$?  Do you generate $N$ values of $x_n$ independently from this discrete uniform distribution or do you use data you have somehow obtained?  How do you know the distribution is Gaussian--how did you test or measure it?

Comment: Please see my edited post. I have added some new information.  Actually, the data are obtained from another experiment. However, they are always uniform. I have not mathematically tested the distribution of the coefficients. I say it has a Gaussian distribution only because of its shape. If you increase signal_length in the code, the shape of the distribution, to a large extent, resembles a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I don't see the CLT here, just the the periodicity of the $cos$ function, how the $X_k$ are calculated, and the fact that $x_n$ are distributed symmetrically around zero. I will try to write an answer elaborating on these...  As for resemblance with Gaussian distribution: there are many unimodal, "bell-shaped" distributions out there, have you checked Gaussianity using a formal statistical test? The thing to look is for fat tails and/or excess kurtosis.